# Helm doesn't see [RELEASE] and [CHART] names during install

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

After `helm template` in gitlab-ci when installing a chart in Kubernetes, Helm does not see [RELEASE] and [CHART] names even if they are hardcoded.

```
eks_deploy_dev:
  stage: eks_deploy_stage
  image: registry.test.net/helm-kubectl:v2.0.13
  before_script:
    - apk add curl
    - helm repo update
    - helm plugin install https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push
    - helm plugin install --version master https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/helm-nexus-push.git
    - helm repo add crash-games-new https://nexus.test.net/repository/charts/ --username "$NEXUS_USERNAME" --password "$NEXUS_PASSWORD"
    - docker login registry.test.net --username "$NEXUS_USERNAME" --password "$NEXUS_PASSWORD"
    - chmod 600 /root/.kube/config
    - helm pull oci://registry.test.net/combined-socket-chart --debug
    - pwd
    - ls -la
    - apk add tree
    - tree
  script:
    - helm repo update
    - tar -xzf combined-socket-chart-1.0.0.tgz
    - ls -la combined-game-chart/helm-values
    - ls -la combined-socket-chart/helm-values/service1
    - if ${WHITELIST_IP}; then SOURCE_IPS=${VPN_IPS}; else SOURCE_IPS="0.0.0.0/0"; fi
    - |
      for game_folder in $(ls combined-socket-chart/helm-values/); do
      game_name=$(basename "$game_folder")
      chart_folder="combined-socket-chart/helm-values/$game_folder"
      echo "Creating Helm template for $game_name..."
      
      helm dependency update $chart_folder
      
      # Construct values as JSON
      values_json="{\"application\":{\"image\":{\"prefix\":\"${ECR_IMAGE_REF}\",\"version\":\"${CI_COMMIT_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_SHA}\"},\"ingress\":{\"rules\":{\"domains\":[\"${DOMAINS}\"]},\"annotations\":{\"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range\":\"${SOURCE_IPS}\"}},\"labels\":{\"team\":\"${TEAM}\",\"cluster\":\"${EKS_CLUSTER}\"}}}"
      
      values_file=$(mktemp)
      echo $values_json >> $values_file
      tree
      tar -xzf combined-socket-chart/helm-values/service1/charts/application-1.4.15.tgz
      tree
      
      helm template $game_name $chart_folder -f $chart_folder/values.yaml -f $chart_folder/values-${ENV}.yaml -f $values_file


      helm upgrade \
              --install \
              --devel \
              --dry-run \
              --kube-context=${EKS_CLUSTER} \
              --atomic \
              --timeout=${DEPLOY_TIMEOUT} \
              --namespace=${NAMESPACE/$EKS_CLUSTER\/} \
              --debug \
              $game_name \
              $chart_folder \
              -f $chart_folder/values.yaml \
              --set application.image.prefix=${ECR_IMAGE_REF},application.image.version=${CI_COMMIT_TAG:-$CI_COMMIT_SHA},application.ingress.rules.domains={$DOMAINS},application.ingress.annotations."nginx\.ingress\.kubernetes\.io/whitelist-source-range"="${SOURCE_IPS}",application.labels.team=${TEAM},application.labels.cluster=${EKS_CLUSTER}
      done
```

My project tree

```
├── combined-socket-chart
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   └── helm-values
│       ├── service1
│       │   ├── Chart.lock
│       │   ├── Chart.yaml
│       │   ├── charts
│       │   │   └── application-1.4.15.tgz
│       │   ├── values-i1.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i2.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i3.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i4.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i5.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i6.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i7.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i8.yaml
│       │   ├── values-i9.yaml
│       │   └── values.yaml
│       └── service2
│           ├── Chart.yaml
│           ├── values-i1.yaml
│           ├── values-i2.yaml
│           ├── values-i3.yaml
│           ├── values-i4.yaml
│           ├── values-i5.yaml
│           ├── values-i6.yaml
│           ├── values-i7.yaml
│           ├── values-i8.yaml
│           ├── values-i9.yaml
│           └── values.yaml
└── combined-socket-chart-1.0.0.tgz
```

Error

```
Error: "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments
Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
helm.go:84: [debug] "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments
Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]
helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/require.ExactArgs.func1
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/require/args.go:39
```

Comment: Can you try to echo `$game_name` and `$chart_folder`, it looks like one of them is NULL